# Basic layout with CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm designing a basic layout using flexbox.

[image]

I've tried the following code but it's not working:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="div1">1</div>
        <div id="div2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3"></div
</div>

#wrapper {display:flex;flex-direction:row;}
#div1, #div2 {display:block;}
#container, #div3 {flex:1};
```

The code can be changed as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use yor `#container` as a vertical flexible container, so you can share the height between `#div1` and `#div2`.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#container,
#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  flex: 1
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#div2 {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="div1"> div 1</div>
        <div id="div2"> div 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3"> div 3</div
</div>
```